How do input pins work?
I am trying to understand properly how buttons work with the pico; I can make them work but I don't understand why it works or if it is the right approach.
I get that I need to add Pin.IN when creating the pin in micropython and that there needs to be an internal resistor (PULL_UP or PULL_DOWN)
For PULL_DOWN, I have a wire going from 3V3 to the button and then to GP15

with the following code:
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

button = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

while True:
    print(button.value())
    sleep(0.1)

For pull up I have a pin that goes from GP15 to the button and then to ground

from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

button = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
while True:
    print(button.value())
    sleep(0.1)

Both of these work but I don't get why; or more specifically I don't understand what Pin.IN actually does:
When the resistor is set to PULL_DOWN GP15 gets 3 volt and I suppose is looking for changes in current (which would be influenced by the button). But when it is set to PULL_UP it looks like that GP15 is sending out current since the other end is ground, meaning it doesn't really function as an input pin?
Could someone explain this in a bit more detail or link a good source? I've been looking around and cannot find anything useful.

Please draw a schematic of how you connected the button.

Setting pull-up or pull-down switches an internal resistor (or something similar) between the input pin and either Vdd or GND.
So you effectively have either of these:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The GPIO pin will read 0 if the input voltage is less than a certain threshold, and 1 if the voltage is higher. For the purposes here you can assume the input gate itself draws zero current and therefore it needs to be connected to something to determine the voltage.
If the switch is open, then the resistor dominates and will pull the input high or low respectively for the two circuits.
If the switch is closed, then the switch dominates (because it has very low resistance compared to the pullup or pulldown resistor) and the input voltage is low or high respectively for the two circuits.
The resistor values are not well controlled, they'll be something like 50~80kΩ. See the appropriate datasheet. Similarly, the input thresholds are a bit variable and are different for rising and falling inputs since they have some hysteresis.
And since mechanical switches "bounce" if you're counting switch presses you'll need something like software debouncing to keep from getting multiple counts.
Adding a series resistor to the switch of 1kΩ can help avoid ESD failures, since fingers can carry charge from a human body.

Think of the GPIO pins as observing the voltage on the pin, rather than supplying or sinking current.
The pull-up or pull-down resistor could be (and often are, depending on MCU) outside the MCU. I would consider these resistors as not really part of the input function of the GPIO circuit, but just a convenience for the user (saves having to add external resistors).
If you have a pull-up resistor, the pin will normally be pulled to Vcc by the resistor so the MCU input is seen as a "1" or "High".  The button would be connected between the input pin and Ground.  When the button is pressed, it will connect the pin to Ground, so the MCU input will be seen as "0" or Low.  The pull-up resistor, rather than the GPIO input, is supplying the current that passes through the button.
Similarly, a pull-down resistor will pull the GPIO input to Ground, with the button pulling the pin to Vcc when pressed.

The notion of a pin being an input or output is from the point of view of the Central Processing Unit (CPU) within the microcontroller (MCU). The CPU is the block of circuitry that actually runs your software.
Being an input pin doesn't mean that it doesn't pass current out. Being made of imperfect transistors, it will output a small current (input leakage current in a datasheet) to detect a LOW input voltage. That current has be drawn from the input pin to pull the pin voltage below the LOW threshold voltage.
Similarly, and more intuitively logically, the input pin will draw an input current that has to be supplied to raise the pin's voltage above the HIGH voltage threshold.
This is a factor when calculating input pull-down and pull-up resistors. The drop in the resistors conducting these pull-up/pull-down input leakage currents must leave a low-enough LOW voltage or high-enough HIGH voltage on the pin to switch it cleanly LOW or HIGH. The currents are small but not negligible and will add up if, for example, using one resistor to pull a lot of unused pins LOW or HIGH.
This is illustrated below (diagram taken from here).

